# How to install mysqlbackup?

Tags: mysql, database-administration, mysql-backup

I would like to use mysqlbackup to do incremental backups. However I can't figure out how to install it.

I have mysql-server installed. The documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.7/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html) seems to suggest it should already be installed but it's not. I'm running mysql on ubuntu.

Comment: mysqlbackup documentation you already have and i did not implement it yet, but if you want to get full as well incremental backup in mysql then there are other ways also like one is by mysqldump and binary logs combination and another one is by percona utility innobackupexe both I have tested..if you interested then I can share you script/document.

Comment: I use [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) to perform backups of my database.  It gives option for taking backup of either the "structure" or both "structure and data" as SQL dump either as a single dump or dump for each table and also "compress" the backup and use timestamp to identify it.

Answer (score 2):

[Mysqlbackup](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.7/en/meb-commands-overview.html) is part of the [MySQL Enterprise Backup](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/backup.html):

> When using the MySQL Enterprise Backup product, you primarily work with the **mysqlbackup** command.

Enterprise Backup, on the otherhand, is part of the [MySQL Enterprise Edition](https://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/) which is available from [Oracle store](https://shop.oracle.com/pls/ostore/f?p=dstore:product:0::NO:RP,6:P6_LPI,P6_PROD_HIER_ID:60720318189220530576677,58095029061520477171389).

Comment: So basically there's no way to install it without paying quite a bit money?

Comment: @pacman, Unfortunately I think you need to pay for it. I haven't seen anything to hint that it'd be available outside of Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install automysqlbackup
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using and what was the output you go when you ran that command?

Comment: I'm running 14.04. There was nothing noteworthy about the output. It just indicated that it succeeded.

Comment: @RockScience - not only is it not in my path, but there is also no file anywhere on my computer with that name.

Comment: @pacman if it indicated that it was successful install I can indeed assure you that it was installed. Run the command "sudo automysqlbackup" and it should start up.

Comment: @JohnCrawford - yes automysqlbackup is installed. I want mysqlbackup to be installed.

Comment: @pacman, Ah I see.  Hmm, after doing a quick Google search I don't believe any such program exists.  Please send me a link to this actual program or even an article talking about it. For the record, I'd strongly recommend using mysqldump in a script file and set up a cron job to run the script on a daily basis.

Comment: @JohnCrawford - Here is the mysqlback link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/3.10/en/mysqlbackup.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use linux.First u can download the install soft from web.
e.g. meb_xxxx.rpm.
Then run the command: `rpm -ivh meb_xxxx.rpm`
The MEB will install in the path /opt/mysql/meb_xxxx default.
Then u can use the mysqlbackup commande in the ./bin/ directory.

Answer (score -3):

You're in luck, someone recently wrote a comprehensive writeup of how to install automysqlbackup on Ubuntu.

https://gist.github.com/janikvonrotz/9488132

They use a different approach to installing it - not using apt-get, but downloading the source and running the install shell script.  I hope this works for you, good luck!